# Django - How to call a session in a module different than views.py?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'd like to call a session that was set at views.py in my forms.py. Is that possible?

I tried to do that but I faced some issues with 'request'.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class NormalForm(forms.Form):

   options = [
       ('TEST','TEST'),
   ]

   options_normalform = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=options,widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'example_form'}), label='')

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       self.option_a = self.request.session['my_session']

    self.options_list = [
        ('a', self.option_a),
        ('b', 'b'),
        ('c', 'c'),
    ]

    self.options_form = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=self.options_list,widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'example_form'}), label='')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ExampleForm, NormalForm

def example(request):
    option_a = '123'
    request.session['my_session'] = option_a

    normalform = NormalForm
    form = ExampleForm(request=request)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'normalform': normalform,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <h1 id="logo">MY APP</h1>
        </header>


        <!-- Options form -->
        <div id="forms">
            <form id="normalform" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{normalform}}
            </form>
            <form id="form" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- End of options form -->


        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="main-footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2017-2017 | my APP </p>
        </footer>
        <!-- End of Footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't try to import the value instead of make a session, because this value will be created inside the same view that I call the form. Therefore I would get a circular error.

I hope that to store this value in a session, and then send it to my form will not raise this circular issue.

P.S. I'm a beginner on programming.

[EDITED] It was included the template and a new form to test if the view is able to find the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we rewrite the form class so it receives the request object in the constructor and stores it in a field. All the other properties will be initialized after that:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.option_a = self.request.session['my_session']

        self.options_list = [
            ('a', self.option_a),
            ('b', 'b'),
            ('c', 'c'),
        ]

        self.fields['options_form'] = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=self.options_list, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'example_form'}), label='')
```

Now, in your view you have to instantiate a form object and pass the request in the constructor call. Note that the context should receive a form instance and not the class or the form will not be rendered:

```
def example(request):
    option_a = '123'
    request.session['my_session'] = option_a
    form = ExampleForm(request=request)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'example/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I'm getting an error: self.option_a = self.request.session['my_session']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: @Filipe oops, sorry - my bad! Replace the line `form = ExampleForm(request)` in the view function with `form = ExampleForm(request=request)`. It should be a keyword argument. I also updated the answer.

Comment: no problem! I'm not getting the error anymore, but the form hasn't rendered. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: @Filipe may be errors in HTML template, or the template file not being found.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: I will wait a bit to try to figure out why I'm not able to render the form. Could you please indicate to me what I should study to understand that way you made the form?

Comment: @Filipe If you edit the question adding the template, I will take a look. I guess [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) would be a good entry point, as usual - the official Django docs are pretty good.

Comment: I edited. I also included a new form (called normal form), to test if the template is being found and It is. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hi, [I read forms' apidocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form) and spot the error I made. If you want to define an attribute `spam` that you want to reference as `form.spam` in the template, you should put it in `Form.fields` dictionary under the key `spam`! So I changed `self.options_form = ...` to `self.fields['options_form'] = ...` so the `options_form` is found and rendered in the template.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much. You save the day!